# Set margin or padding on span element

Tags: jquery, css

Currently I'm working on the WP theme alteration. And I'm stuck on one point.
The theme has the span class `meta-sep` which has a vertical bar as a separator. And I need to move the bar up a little (1px), as shown in the example:

Currently: http://s29.postimg.org/hnhckw7vb/bar_1.jpg

What's needed: http://s10.postimg.org/zbqekmtfd/bar_2.jpg

I've tried everything: margin, padding .meta-sep, firebugging a bit and it simply doesnt work! I've spend half of a day on this matter.

The theme is located here: http://wordpress.org/themes/groundwork

I would very much appreciate any help or guidance.

Comment: Please provide your current HTML and CSS code.

Comment: <span class="meta-sep"> | </span> no CSS for this row

Answer (score 0):

`span` element is inline by default so you cannot apply the margin or padding to the top and bottoms. To an inline element, you can only assign left or right padding. To make this work you need to change the display to `block` or `inline-block`.

Comment: Thank You, but still it doesn't work properly. I've add block and inline-block to .met-sep but neither margin nor padding works.